# Split a string to hold first few values only

Tags: javascript

I have a string,

```
var str = '12990|2346|5771|22523|73|16660|16770|16205|8407|13691|'
```

I want to split this string to hold first five values like 12990|2346|5771|22523|73

I have tried with below logic

```
str.split('|').slice(0,5)
```

But it returns in an array format. I do not want it like that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can join the sliced array using `join()`

```
str.split('|').slice(0, 5).join('|');
```

```js
var str = '12990|2346|5771|22523|73|16660|16770|16205|8407|13691|';
console.log(str.split('|').slice(0, 5).join('|'));
```

OR, regex can also be used with `match()`

```
str.match(/\d+(\|\d+){4}/)[0]
```

```js
var str = '12990|2346|5771|22523|73|16660|16770|16205|8407|13691|';
console.log(str.match(/\d+(\|\d+){4}/)[0]);
```

The regex will match one or more digits followed by four instances of pipe followed by digits.

1. `\d+`: Match one or more digits
2. `\|`: Match pipe `|` literal
3. `{4}`: Match preceding group exactly four times

`match` returns an array, to get the complete match use `[0]`.